# Smartest way to double loop over a data frame (comparing rows to each other with a Levenshtein Dist) in R?

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I cooked a df of paramStrings over several records:

```
             idName                                          Str
1         Аэрофлот_Эконом 95111000210102121111010100111000100110101001
2        Аэрофлот_Комфорт 95111000210102121111010100111000100110101001
3         Аэрофлот_Бизнес 96111000210102121111010100111000100110101001
4       Трансаэро_Дисконт 26111000210102120000010100001010000010001000
5 Трансаэро_Туристический 26111000210002120000010100001010000010001000
6        Трансаэро_Эконом 26111000210002120000010100001010000010001000
```

Now I need to compare each one against others with a levenshtainDist, which works as a function(str1,str2), so I need obviously double loop for that. However, I am pretty sure there shall be a neat vectorised (apply/lapply/sapply) way of doing that, however I couldn't find any similar solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `adist` computes a generalized Levenshtein distance. Is that what you need?

Assuming you have your data in a data.frame, using: `adist(mydf$Str)` will return a matrix with the distances between each pair of the `Str` column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a data.frame I think the best way to do a double loop is a `lapply`/`sapply` double loop which works great with `data.frames`:

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:20,b=1:20) #example dataframe

a <- data.frame(lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {
                  sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(y) {
                    sum( df1[x,2], df1[y,2]) #I just add the two cells (I only use the second column here for the demonstration) / replace with your function
                  }
                  )
                } 
                )
    )
colnames(a) <- 1:20 #change names
```

The first `lapply` will return `nrow(df1)` lists and inside each list will be a vector of `nrow(df1)` observations (the evaluation of the function). This means that you will have a `nrow(df1)`x`nrow(df1)` list which is very convenient to convert into a `data.frame` as I do above. Thus you have a `nrow(df1)`x`nrow(df1)` `data.frame`.

The output of the above:

```
> str(a)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ 1 : int  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ 2 : int  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
 $ 3 : int  4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
 $ 4 : int  5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ...
 $ 5 : int  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
 $ 6 : int  7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
 $ 7 : int  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
 $ 8 : int  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ...
 $ 9 : int  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
 $ 10: int  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
 $ 11: int  12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 ...
 $ 12: int  13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ...
 $ 13: int  14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 ...
 $ 14: int  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 ...
 $ 15: int  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ...
 $ 16: int  17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ...
 $ 17: int  18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 ...
 $ 18: int  19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 ...
 $ 19: int  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ...
 $ 20: int  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...
```

You could even add that to a function and make a generic way of double-looping.

P.S. please keep in mind that using any function of the family `apply` is not vectorised but works better than a `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to compute the combinations of rows you want to compare and then use 'mapply'.  I am assuming that you want to compare two rows at a time from your matrix:

```
# get combinations
cbn <- combn(nrow(your_data), 2)  # take 2 at a time
ans <- mapply(dist_function
            , your_data[cbn[1, ], 1]
            , your_data[cbn[2, ], 1]
            )
```