# Match rows across multiple columns but ignore NAs in Rstudio

Tags: r, duplicates, na, matching

I am using Rstudio to identify duplicate accounts in a data frame.
I want to find a way to identify any duplicates across certain columns but I am running into a problem with NAs.
In the lines below, I would want these 2 rows to be considered a match if they have the same first, last, dob, and gender but given I have an NA in gender, the 2 rows are not duplicates given I create the is_duplicate flag based on the concatenated Match column.

Any ideas how to adjust for that?

---

Id -- First -- Last -- DOB -- Gender -- Match -- Is_duplicates

---

123 -- Ali -- Smith -- 1993 -- Female -- **AliSmith1993Female** -- 0

---

435 -- Ali -- Smith -- 1993 -- NA -- **AliSmith1993NA** -- 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fuzzy matching using agrep ?
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/agrep

or maybe this post will help you?

[Smartest way to double loop over a data frame (comparing rows to each other with a Levenshtein Dist) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088160/smartest-way-to-double-loop-over-a-data-frame-comparing-rows-to-each-other-with)